# How to record button clicks and then play them back?

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I have an app with `3 x 3` buttons, each of which has a short sound attached to it. I have another button called `Record`, so when this `Record` button is clicked, I want to record in which order each button is clicked.

I dont want to record it as `.wav`, `.mp3`, `.ogg` or any other media format, as it will be very difficult for some phones and as the consequence the app will have a very big latency.

Does anyone know of any techniques to do this? Like record it in a text file then playback the order of the button-clicks? I like this scenario, but unfortunately don't know what I should use.

Is this even the right way about going about this, or no?

Comment: Do you want to save it forever, or just while that activity is open?

Comment: @Mike, lets say i want to save it in a text file, and then playback it from textfile

Comment: Maybe you could write the button names in the order they were pressed into a String array and write it into a text file. Perhaps you should read this:
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42

Comment: @Mike, i can read and write in to the textfile. The problem is timestamp, how to play them in order+time. There is a gap between button clicks and this have to be followed

Comment: ahh, in that case you could call System.currentTimeMillis() and compare this one to the last one, so that you put the stamp next to the String in your file.  Then use a Thread.sleep with the time inserted into the input.  So the file might look like 
Button1 0
Button2 143
Button3 76

so button2 was pressed 143ms after button1 and button3 was pressed 76ms after button2